# Инициализация беззнакового массива

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно задать константный массив-сигнатуру. Сейчас делаю так

```
byte sgn[] = {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0xFF};
```

Вопрос: можно ли его как-то задать не кастуя каждый элемент к `byte`?

Что-то типа такого

```
byte [] sgn = Array.fromRaw(0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF)
```

Comment: В Java нет беззнаковых типов, и ваш `(byte)0xFF` превратится в `-1`, тоже самое без каста можно получить написав `-0x01`, либо просто `-1` в виде десятичного числа.

Comment: @Vartlok я знаю, что нет беззнаковых типов. Именно поэтому я вынужден кастовать

Comment: Вы понимаете что `0xFF` - это 255? и что у `byte` диапазон значений от -128 до 127? Вы пытаетесь число запихнуть туда, куда оно не влезает.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov так всё же: почему вы не хотите этот массив записать как `byte sgn[] = { -1, -40, -1 };`?

Comment: @Vartlok да, я понимаю, что в итоге я получу -1

Comment: @Regent Я открываю hex-редактор и переписываю байты. Мне просто влом их еще вручную конвертировать. И читабельность кода упадет. Потом нужно будет вспоминать откуда оно появилось

Comment: можно написать `Array.fromRaw` самому, в стандартной библиотеке я такого не вспомню. Есть `ByteBuffer.writeInt`, но он пишет 4 байта

Comment: @AntonShchyrov в таком случае остаётся только написать метод, который массив `int`, заданный в виде `new int[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF }`, будет преобразовывать в массив `byte` кастом в цикле.

Comment: @Regent Спасибо. Я думал, что есть что-то стандартное

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простого способа нет, только если написать свою функцию.

```
private byte[] bytes(int... ints) {
    byte b[] = new byte[ints.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        b[i] = (byte) ints[i];
    }
    return b;
}
```